# In Java I need to read a text file and put each line in a separate array. But every time I read the text file I cannot split the lines

Tags: java, arrays

In Java I need to read a text file(the file contains three lines and I need to put each line in a double arrray). But I cant split the line. This is the code I have so far. But I don't know how to proceed:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class FedEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        //Read the file
        FileReader file = new FileReader("info.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);

        String text = " ";
        String line = br.readLine();

        while(line != null)
        {
            text += line;
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        //Print the text file.
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to put `String`s in a `double` array, and why? There aren't any arrays in your code at all?

Comment: Can you add the content of the file.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't split the line"? You don't know how? You get an error?

Comment: @AlexQuilliam No, OP simply concatenates all lines. Once they are all concatenated, it's of course impossible to split them...

Comment: At least append some line breaks "\"" after each line maybe?

Comment: Do you want each line as a separate `String`? If so, try using an `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: @AlexQuilliam i don't know how, this code reads the text but I don't know how to split it so the console displays the information in 3 lines. Also should I populate my array after the while?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want t read a file of numbers and put it inside Array of doubles, If that so you can see this code:

> Note: I have used `try-with-resource` to prevent source leaks.

```
public class FedEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Read the file
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("info.txt"))) {
            String line;
            List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
            }
            System.out.println(doubles);
        }

    }
}
```

*File Sample:*

```
343
6787
19
22
58
0
```

*Output Sample:*

```
[343.0, 6787.0, 19.0, 22.0, 58.0, 0.0]
```

---

There is no need to add text together, So if you want to just display the content of the file line-by-line, try this:

```
public class FedEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Read the file
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("info.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

*File Sample:*

```
343
6787
19
22
58
0
```

*Output Sample:*

```
343
6787
19
22
58
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this using Java 8 features:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileLineByLine {

    private static List<Double> file2doubles(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return stream.map(Double::parseDouble).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        List<Double> doubles = file2doubles(args[0]);

        System.out.println(doubles);
    }
}
```

You can make this a bit more general by parameterizing the line transformation, see here https://gist.github.com/sorokod/818ccd65cad967cdecb7dbf4006e4fa0